# Compiling assimp from source does not generate libassimp file

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

So I compiled the assimp library with cmake using the x64_x86 developer command prompt that was said to be required. (When I tried using the regular console cmake did an error that it could not find 'the cl compiler').

After some time it finally compiled without errors with the following commands:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF
cmake --build .
```

It built 3 files:

```
C static library zlibstaticd.lib
CXX shared library ..\bin\assimp-vc142-mtd.dll
CXX executable ..\bin\unit.exe
```

But there was no libassimp.a or libassimp.so that I can link against in MinGW. I tried just linking with te dll in my own project with:

```
-L\"{assimp root directory}/bin\"
-lassimp-vc142-mtd
```

and it failed with "undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()"

How can i get the lib file to link against?

Comment: Hmm. "libassimp.a or libassimp.so" sounds something that you will end up with on Linux, and not MS-Windows.

Comment: Looks like you built it with the MSVC tool-chain (`cl` compiler is MSVC) you need build with the GCC/G++/MinGW tool chain.

Comment: well now that I think of it you're right. Oh, now my question is basically void. That takes me to the undefined reference. I am definitely linking the library. GLFW and GLEW already link the same way.

Comment: @RichardCritten ok how should I tell cmake to use g++ instead of MSVC? -G "MinGW Makefiles"??

Comment: The Undefined Reference is caused by the different tool-chains name-mangling the exported symbols ddifferently.

Comment: Yes, I got to this issue:  https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/4586 will see where I get.

Comment: You may just want to install msys2 and have it install MinGW and  assimp https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp

Comment: @drescherjm ok I did that and now it should be working. For some reason my project segfaults on windows where it did not on Linux, but it's fixable and when I am sure that it works I'll post the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed MSYS2, replaced my existing MinGW installation with MSYS, libraries installed flawlessly and everything works now.

My mistake was that:

1. I was compiling the library with VS C++ toolkit while I'm compiling my project with MInGW make and g++
2. even after I compiled assimp the correct way, version 5.2.4 couldn't find some header, 5.2.3 and some older versions compiled successfully, but failed some unit tests (God knows why). Seemed to always hit some unresolved issue on GitHub. Never again compiling libraries from source.